# Configure Eclipse string externalization wizard that value is used as key

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, string-externalization

I use Eclipse to externalize my language dependent strings.
How can I change its default behavior in the following way:

In the default the keys are numbered 0 .. n.
I would like the key to be the value. 
Even better would be if the key would be the value and all spaces replaced by "_".

If a configuration is not possible I would like to program it myself. Could anyone point me to the starting point (the source of eclipse) and how I would integrate it once I am done?

Many thanks for any advice.